# PHPExcel.php doesn't save file .xls

Tags: php, linux, save, phpexcel

I have a seriously problem, when i execute my script to generate an excel file, it show a blank page.

This is the code:

http://pastebin.com/fb3KMYHv

The script run on Linux server (Hetzner is the hoster) and if there are a lot of records of my query it doesn't work.
Thanks.

Comment: We are not a debugging service. YOU need to at LEAST do some basic debugging yourself: turn on error_reporting, turn on display_errors, check logs, etc...

Comment: Obvious things to check for in the logs are exceeding memory and timeout

Comment: Why are you instantiating two writers though? You only need one writer for the one format, and you can still save a file multiple times (to disk and to browser output)... but you're adding extra memory overhead

Comment: Or even save the file to disk, and then stream it directly to the browser using [readfile()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php), cut out all the overheads of a second save()